# How can I get this Fairplay HLS setup to work?

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, fairplay

I'm running:

```
mediafilesegmenter movie.mp4 --encrypt-key-file=key.bin --streaming-key-delivery -t 10 --file-base=.`
```

where key.bin is just `aaaaa...` (32 a's). Then, in my `prog_index.m3u8` file, I set it up as:

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://192.168.1.27/just_key.bin",KEYFORMAT="identity",IV=0x6161616161...
```

However, when I try to run it, I get:

`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16040), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c0250200 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16040 "(null)"}`.

`just_key.bin` is just 16 `a`'s.

Any ideas what might be the issue? Is there an easy way to get Fairplay going otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

FairPlay uses `SAMPLE-AES` encryption, not `AES-128`. Try with:

`METHOD=SAMPLE-AES`